# How set LIKE criteria for specific chars in Jet, Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, jet

I have field `UPon` in my table with following values :

```
1,15,28
2,17,28
121,217,33
181,17
66,45,1171
988,38
17
```

For example, I need result for record which contain only `17`

Now, if I use `UPon LIKE '%17%'` then I'll get records bellow:

```
2,17,28
121,217,33
181,17
66,45,1171
17
```

But, I need sql query return only records `2,17,28`, `181,17`and `17`

I can't use `,` in criteria because this char can be anywhere or not be at all.

Comment: As for SQL I recommend putting this in an ARRAY and check whether it contains element `17`. That would discard every row that does not contain element `17` eg. `66,45,1171` would not be present in result.

Comment: you could just expand your query to or the 4 cases - i.e. = '17'  or like '%,17,%' or like '17,%' or like '%,17'

Comment: I agree with Matt, but sometimes we have to work with what we've got. You could still use the Like operator but instead against function on the column that replaces commas with white space. Something like Replace(ColumnName,',',' ') Like "% 17 %' will catch most of them. It's nasty but it will work

Comment: Thx everyone. I need answers not opinions, just like Ciaran said "we have to work with what we've got", no hard feeling, please... Unfortunately, I must use record(s) in this way... Why, isn't meter now...  NDJ's solution is what I have to use. Thx everyone for fast answers, again :) This is the best forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(making this an answer as it's what you decided to go with and will make it easier for any future readers to find, rather than in the comments)

you could just expand your query to or the 4 cases - i.e. = '17' or like '%,17,%' or like '17,%' or like '%,17'